# select users from different database based on client id in userdetails service in spring boot oauth2 authorization server

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I need to implement custom userdetailsservice in spring boot oauth2 server . if I need to authorize a user using client1 I need to check user  from database1 and for client2 I need to check user from database2. I am using jwt based tokens .

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: No I haven't tried anything as I have no idea to implement it . But I have implemented oauth2 server with in memory  jwt token service and in memory users

Comment: just i need a way to find curren client in userdetails service